# React Native - Open browser in the background

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-chrome, browser, expo

i want to open a url with react native. But i dont want to go to the browser page.When i clicked  button, it should open a url in the backgorund. But i want to stay in my app . Is there way to do it with expo?

I looked for result for a long time but did not found any solution about it.
I have tried background-feth, react native-linking, window.open and etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Opening an URL in the background without switching to the browser page is a bit tricky in React Native (Expo) due to security and limitations. Expo does not provide a direct way to achieve this behavior as it goes against their security principles.**

However, you can use the `InAppBrowser` module to open a `URL` within your app. This module allows you to display web content inside your React Native app.

you can refer to [this][1]

You can install it using:

```
expo install expo-in-app-browser
```

For example:-

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import * as WebBrowser from 'expo-in-app-browser';

const App = () => {
  const openURL = async () => {
    try {
      await WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://www.google.com', {
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error opening URL', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Open URL" onPress={openURL} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

To open an url within the app you may [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webview). This library will display the website based on the url given while staying in the application.